# Language switcher with flags - Polylang WP plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-polylang

I have installed Polylang WP plugin for one site.. and need to add flags but its look like there is no option or any tutorial how to do this.. If anybody have some solution for this will be great..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In meantime, maybe I have on.. I do not want to use some big scripts or something so I did this simple one.. I will write here if somebody else need it..

1.) I create sidebar in my theme, and add it to header

```
<div class="drop-dl">
  <a class="lang-chose" href="#"><img src=""> Chose language</a>
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
```

2.) Then I go to admin page and on widget section I add Language Switcher to Sidebar to get Unsorted Lists from languages

3.) and I add small script and css code to get this work, here is [CodePen demo link](http://codepen.io/dados/pen/OMzqbK)

Any suggestion is welcome :) Because this solution work with "Polylang widget", the good part is that you have addition options and functionality to chose from widget "Language Switcher"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply but it will help someone.

You can do this with some php code. As you 're using php, you have more control over positioning the widget in template.

```
if(function_exists('pll_the_languages')){
    pll_the_languages( array( 'show_flags' => 1,'show_names' => 0  ));
}
```

Obviously there's a good documentation at official site.

https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/#pll_the_language